# how to call a method in a windows from another method in asp.net web-api

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api

I have a C# solution which has 2 projects: a windows forms project (desktop) and a asp.net web-api project (REST service). I am trying to call the method **enableMachine()** in **Form1.cs** from the **Post()** method in **ValuesController.cs**, but though I referenced the namespace it shows errors. If I define **enableMachine()** as static it works, but I cannot do so because I also need to instantiate another object within this method. Any ideas on how to solve this problem ? Thanks in advance !

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using RestLayer.Models;
using ValidatorConnector;

namespace RestLayer.Controllers
{
    public class ValuesController : ApiController
    {

        // POST api/values
        public void Post()
            {
               ...     
            }
       }
}



using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using log4net;

namespace ValidatorConnector
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

     public Form1()
        {
         ...
        }

    public void enableValidator()
    {
        ...
    }

}
```

Comment: You are calling a method defined in a windows form class in an web service api? This clearly needs to be reworked. You need to pull the common code out into a class that is used by both your web form app and web service app.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. No, I am calling a method defined in a windows form class in Project1 from a web service class in Project2. Please elaborate your suggestion a little further.

Answer (score 1):

Best thing to do is to separate common functionality into a separate project that does not depend on Forms or on Asp.Net. Then give this assembly to ASP.Net and to WinForms projects as a dependency, then you'll be able to call your methods from both projects.

Comment: Thanks! what kind of project should I select ?

Comment: You need to create a library project

Comment: OK. Thanks for your prompt response !